# PHP SQL | Find row in table, if not exist, use other table

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I am working on a page on which users can track the status of an order. When the user requests an order, they will first need to wait for an employee to approve the order. Then, the record is deleted out of the `aanvraag` table and inserted into the `datas` table.

Since I also want to provide the customers waiting for approval with the status, I tried the code below to check whether the record exists in the `aanvraag` table. If not, `datas` table must be used to fetch information.

I have a check called `$ggk` which checks whether the record is in `aanvraag` or `datas`. The problem I am facing now is that I cannot fetch the data out of either tables and get a blank page returned (because `$ggk == 2`). I have been working on this issue for about a day now and cannot seem to find the issue. Anyone knows what I have must been looking over?

P.s. I am planning to encrypt the ID in order to prevent users accessing other customers order data.

```
<?php
include "db.php";
include "functions.php";
session_start();

if (isset($_GET['case'])) {
    $id = $_GET['case'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `aanvraag` WHERE `ID`='$id'";
    $resul = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resul);
    
    $ggk = 2;
    if (mysqli_num_rows($resul) > 0) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `aanvraag` WHERE `ID`='$id'";
    $resul = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resul);
    $ggk = 0;
    }else{
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `datas` WHERE `id`='$id'";
    $resul2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resul);
    $ggk = 1;
    }
```

Comment: can't you just use UNION to combine your queries?

Comment: Please never never use string concatenation to build SQL queries, especially if you aren't even escaping the values. Prepared statements are much more secure

Comment: Also, what **exactly** is not working with the given code? What have you tried to debug your problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase I have the $ggk in place to check if the record is in the datas or aanvraag table. When $ggk = 2, it means that there is an error in the checking process (otherwise $ggk would be 0 or 1) and thus it returns a blank page.

Comment: Is that software develpoed by you. Deleting rows from database when status changes sounds dangerous. It would be much better to have status column telling that order is approved and then relation to datas table. I know, this isn't scope of this question. But as a system architecht that approach sounds like a disaster.

Comment: "Returns a blank page" sounds strange - does this mean that an error happens that you haven't caught yet? Which error level are you using? Is there anything written to your server's error log?

Comment: @NicoHaase It is working now. Under the code above I used an if statement to check whether $ggk = 2. Is that is the case, it returned a blank page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you repeat same query twice. You don't need it. Simply turn over condition. Also in query where you select from datas table you have a typo. You use `$resul` instead of `$resul2`. Also typo for `$sql` variable

```
if (isset($_GET['case'])) {
    $id = $_GET['case'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `aanvraag` WHERE `ID`='$id'";
    $resul = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resul);

    $ggk = 2;
    if (mysqli_num_rows($resul) < 0) {
        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `datas` WHERE `id`='$id'";
        $resul2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql2);
        $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resul2);
        $ggk = 1;
    }
}
```

Also this kind of SQL's are very dangerous! Please, use PDO and prepare statements https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Also the approach you have used is not very good. Why do you move data form one table to other? Add one more column where you can track status of order.